# My WordPress installation doesn't load correct template

Tags: loop, page-template, template-hierarchy

For whatever reason there are some odd things going on with my theme, I feel like it's such a fickle install and some times I wonder how it runs.

Anyway, I'm having a few different post types, created using the plugin `Pods`.

In this case I have a custom post type `integration` and as such I made the template files `category-integration.php` and `single-integration.php`, respectively.

I have 3 environments, across which this is creating different results (local, staging and prod). On local and staging the correct template is not being loaded correctly.
The steps I took was to create the php files, and then create the category `Integration` in which template file I just load the same-named pod elements.

However, all I'm getting is an empty page.

On our production environment, the category is created as a page, which (in my opinion) is not only wrong, but also further causes confusion.

If I go to `/integrationer` the wpadmin-bar doesn't even reflect that it's a category, by giving the `edit category` button. Its as if  that specific page is completely out of the loop.

This is a tough thing to describe, so let me know if I need to add further information.

Could this at all be related to cleaning up the database? I'm thinking perhaps WP has created some confusion through having both a page, category and pod named similarly.

I should also mention I am now (although not until yesterday) also experiencing the same issue with my `/blog` and `/support` templates, where the templates are no longer being loaded either (instead they are returning 404).

Also, I am aware that this sounds very much like a permalink issue, so I tried resetting them (selecting another option, then back to our intended permalink structure) but with no difference.

Comment: Hi,
Indeed it looks like a premalink issue (wordpress can be really confused if you have several contents (pages/categories) with the same url).

Did you try to use "Rewrite Rules Inspector" plugin (https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/) to see that WP identify when you test the urls with an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

Installing the plugin, as mentioned above, `Rewrite Rules Inspector` indicated nothing wrong at all.

However, installing the plugin `No Category Base (WPML)` and simply activated it, was enough to resolve the issue in every instance of it returning an error.

I am afraid this might indicate something very wrong with my installation, but either way I'm up'n'running now.

Thanks for inputs!